# error: can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line 8, column 65:"

Tags: antora

yml file on Antora using powershell so I am getting this error, please help me out to resolve it."error: can not read an implicit mapping pair; a colon is missed at line 8, column 65:"

I have tried adding colon to line number 8

```
site:
  title: Antora Demo Site
  url: https://example.org/docs 
  start_page: antora-project::index-template.adoc 
content:
  sources:
  - url:
    home/Users/rashmi.p1/Sample/antora-project/content/feature1 
  - url:
    home/Users/rashmi.p1/Sample/antora-project/content/feature2
    start_path: docs  
ui:
  bundle:
    url:
    home/Users/rashmi.p1/Sample/antora-project/resources
    snapshot: true
```

I am expecting compilation should start and generate the website

Comment: You are missing some space only.

Answer (score 3):

Check if you have quotes. Escape them with `\"Sometext\"`. Example YAML:

```
---
title: Bad relationships still require work. Don't compromise
lastUpdate: 19 July 2021
tags: ['personal', 'relationships', 'compromise']
slug: bad-relationships-require-work
meta:
  title: Bad relationships still require work. Don't compromise
  description: "ERROR HERE The relationship is bad, therefore I can maintain it with less work. ERROR HERE" That's usually a sneaky fallacy.
---
```

See `ERROR HERE`. Quotes should have been escaped

Answer (score 2):

Under `sources:`, the URL should be on the same line as `- url:`, and I think you need to specify the branches to use.

As defined, your URLs are relative, but look like maybe they should be absolute. Provided that those paths resolve correctly from the folder where you invoke Antora, they should work fine.

The `bundle:` URL must point to a ZIP file of a bundled Antora UI. You cannot simply use a folder that represents a UI. In my example below, I've replaced the URL you were using with the URL for Antora's default UI.

So your playbook file should look more like:

```
site:
  title: Antora Demo Site
  url: https://example.org/docs 
  start_page: antora-project::index-template.adoc 
content:
  sources:
  - url: home/Users/rashmi.p1/Sample/antora-project/content/feature1
    branches: HEAD
    start_path: docs
  - url: home/Users/rashmi.p1/Sample/antora-project/content/feature2
    branches: HEAD
    start_path: docs  
ui:
  bundle:
    url: https://gitlab.com/antora/antora-ui-default/-/jobs/artifacts/master/raw/build/ui-bundle.zip?job=bundle-stable
    snapshot: true
```

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same exception, but not for same issue. My issue was under **description:**, which is under **parameters:**. There I kept some space only by mistake. After removing the space, it worked.

You can find it in this image for bette understanding:

[image: you can find in this image for better understating]

Hope it helps.

Comment: How is this answer related to Antora?